# Cannot find module 'selenium-webdriver'

Tags: javascript, npm

I'm trying to automate test with AXE from [here](https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core-npm/tree/develop/packages/webdriverjs)

So I edited the script (index.js) like this

```
var AxeBuilder = require('@axe-core/webdriverjs');
var WebDriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new WebDriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

driver.get('https://www.mywebsite.com').then(function () {
  new AxeBuilder(driver).analyze(function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
      // Handle error somehow
    }
    console.log(results);
  });
});
```

And run it with node with `node index`

But I got this error message

```
C:\Users\USER\Desktop\audit>node index
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:928
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module 'selenium-webdriver'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\USER\node_modules\@axe-core\webdriverjs\dist\axe-injector.js
- C:\Users\USER\node_modules\@axe-core\webdriverjs\dist\index.js
- C:\Users\USER\Desktop\audit\index.js
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:925:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\node_modules\←[4m@axe-core←[24m\webdriverjs\dist\axe-injector.js:15:34)
←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: [
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\USER\\node_modules\\@axe-core\\webdriverjs\\dist\\axe-injector.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\USER\\node_modules\\@axe-core\\webdriverjs\\dist\\index.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\audit\\index.js'←[39m
  ]
}
```

### Some info's

> node -v 15.7.0 //
> npm -v 6.14.11

npm fund

```
system32@1.0.0
    +-- https://opencollective.com/core-js
    | `-- core-js@3.8.3
    `-- https://github.com/sponsors/isaacs
      `-- glob@7.1.6
```

package.json

```
 {
  "name": "system32",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@axe-core/webdriverjs": "^4.1.0",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

Thanks in advance